# how to write the matlab code "tf2ss" in scilab?

Tags: matlab, scilab

I´m trying to solve some examples from a book that are written in MATLAB code in Scilab.

```
num = [1 0];
den = [1 14 56 160];
[A,B,C,D] = tf2ss(num,den)
```

I tried copying it as it is in Scilab but I get the following error:

```
Wrong number of output arguments
```

Comment: [`tf2ss`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.2/en_US/tf2ss.html) only has one output in SciLab, you need to read the documentation and work out how that corresponds to the MATLAB's implementation. They are not the same language, you will have to work to translate between them

Answer (score 3):

While in MATLAB your inputs for `tf2ss` should be coefficients of polynomials, in Scilab, the only input should be a rational matrix, as you can see in the [help page](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/tf2ss.html). Also, in MATLAB, the outputs are the ABCD matrices of the system, but Scilab returns a object of type `state-space`. If you want the ABCD matrices, you need to use `abcd`.

You can create the polynomials using Scilab's `%s` as variable:

```
num = 1*%s + 0;
den = 1*%s^3 + 14*%s^2 + 56*%s + 160;
sl  = tf2ss(num/den);
[A,B,C,D] = abcd(sl);
```

Comment: The 1 coefficent in front of monomials is superfluous, please edit.

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet I know, and I expect the asker to realize that by themselves upon seeing it, but I still decided to write the `1`s to show explicitly where all the coefficients would go in the construction of a polynomial and avoid possible confusions. What is the down side of writing it explicitly?

Comment: No problem. Another way to relate Matlab's way vs. Scilab's way of defining polynoms is to use `poly`, i.e. `num = poly([160 56 14 1],'s','coeff')`